# Display message in XSL formatting features for an RTF field in SDL Tridion 2011 Sp1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have added some xsl formatting features to one RTF field in schema.

I have used the following snippet in it.  For any error, I need to stop component save and display some custom message to user.

```
<xsl:message terminate="yes">
         <xsl:value-of select="'Some error message'"/>
</xsl:message>
```

Its stopping the component save, but not displaying the message.

Can any one letme know is there any better way of doing it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

XSLT templates here cannot be used to display messages, only to transform content.

If you want to show an error message to the users, I'd recommend to check these 2 blogs:

[Validating Content on Save - part 1](http://nunolinhares.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/validating-content-on-save-part-1-of.html)

[Validating Content on Save - part 2](http://www.curlette.com/?p=913)